# Individual Custom Fields in Participant List (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, civievent, participants, civicrm-event

I have a general participant list for a set of events.

I need to add an Individual Custom Field, but this field is not accessible in the Event report column selection.

Are there any plugins or workarounds to access these fields in the Participant Report?

Comment: Is the custom field an event field or a participant field?

Answer (score 1):

Install [ExtendedReport](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) by Eileen, It provides additional reports with lots of options.

Or make sure you have 'Is this Field Searchable?' option checked for the custom field that you want on the report. If not then edit the custom field and check the option 'Is this Field Searchable?'.

Thanks

Pradeep